# Hiding rows using VB

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to hide each row that contains a cell filled with red. Here is my code:

```
Sub AstInv()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant

    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sheet2")
    Set myArray = myTable.ListColumns("Código de Barras2").Range

    For Each cell In myArray
        If Rng.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            rw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Each time I run it, I get this error:

> Compile error: Invalid outside procedure

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Change “Rng” and “rw” to “cell”

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit disjointed and attempts to use variables that have not been dimmed or instantiated.

```
Sub AstInv()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myArray As range

    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")
    Set myArray = myTable.ListColumns("Código de Barras2").Range

    For Each cell In myArray
        If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- > Compile error: Invalid outside procedure

  means that you have some random text at the top of your module (outside all Subs), as in:

---

```
random  ' <- Invalid outside procedure

Sub AstInv1()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
...
```

---

But there are more issues:

- It is unlikely that you have a table named "Sheet2"
- Your ActiveSheet (the sheet currently visible) may not contain the intended table / ListObject
- myArray is declared as Variant when it should be Range
- Rng and rw objects are undeclared and, as mentioned, are not connected to any other objects

To fix them

- Use `Option Explicit` - this will force you to declare all variables
- Check your objects' names and location
- In the code call your objects explicitly

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AstInv()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myCol As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set myTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")   'Check names
    Set myCol = myTable.ListColumns("Código de Barras2").Range

    For Each cell In myCol
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Interior.Color = vbRed)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

This version uses an AutoFilter and shows how to avoid errors when objects are missing

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoFilterRedCells()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, col As Long

    On Error Resume Next    'Ignore expected errors

        Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1") 'Check names
        col = tbl.ListColumns("Código de Barras2").Range.Column

    On Error GoTo 0         'Stop ignoring errors

    If col > 0 Then tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=col, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill

End Sub
```

Comment: Paul, thank you! I have never used VB (as is painfully obvious). I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.